# Discussion Board

Tags: discussion-board, anonymous-access

Good Afternoon,
I have a discussion board that I would like to remove the latest reply from being seen.
Can someone assist.
I have tried multiple views but no getting the option.
I have already changed the create by, modified by from name to id.
It is responses I would like to turn anonymous.